# ArcMap exporting nonsensical data to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I am trying to make a copy of a feature class to make some edits to it. The feature class I am trying to make a copy of is a File Geodatabase Feature Class, and I am trying to export it as a shapefile by clicking 'Data -> Export Data...' from the table of contents. This creates an output file without any errors, but when I add the new exported data back to the map and open the attribute table, I just get garbled mess.

A portion of the original attribute table:

[image]

The same fields of the copied attribute table:

[image]

No idea why this is happening as I'm not getting an error message and it seems a fairly routine operation that I'm pretty sure I have carried out before... I note as well that not all of the rows have been exported.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when exporting to a new feature class, inside a new file geodatabase? Curious whether the results differ - if not, perhaps try to export to .shp from the new fgdb, could be an issue with the existing database itself?

Comment: It's not that all the rows haven't been exported, they have, it's that the import has failed, corrupting data until all-out failure.

Comment: Your original file look like it has almost three-million records.  Maybe you are exporting so much data that you are violating the 2GB limit on shapefile size?

Comment: The dBase table structure used by shapefiles is more restrictive than FGDB. It could be that some of the columns are not dBase-compliant.

Comment: I'd hide fields one by one and tried to export few selected. Also count of exported rows is less than original.

Comment: Just checked in ArcCatalog and the exported shapefile is 2.08 GB. It's working fine to export it as a gdb feature class, so exceeding the shapefile size limit does seem to have been the issue.